# How do I include inline JavaScript in Haml?

Tags: javascript, jquery, haml

How can I write something like this to include in a template, but in Haml?

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('body').addClass( 'test' );
} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 259, accepted):

```
:javascript
    $(document).ready( function() {
      $('body').addClass( 'test' );
    } );
```

Docs: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#javascript-filter

Answer (score 29):

You can actually do what Chris Chalmers does in his answer, but you must make sure that HAML doesn't parse the JavaScript. This approach is actually useful when you need to use a different type than `text/javascript`, which is was I needed to do for `MathJax`.

You can use the `plain` filter to keep HAML from parsing the script and throwing an illegal nesting error:

```
%script{type: "text/x-mathjax-config"}
  :plain
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
      tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]
      }
    });
```

Comment: The :plain filter is very useful to fix the javascript template issue. Thanks!

I'm using fileupload-jquery (https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), which much include js template in haml, and only :plain filter works!

for more detail, read my answer.

Answer (score 19):

So i tried the above :javascript which works :) However HAML wraps the generated code in CDATA like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready( function() {
       $('body').addClass( 'test' );
    } );
  //]]>
</script>
```

The following HAML will generate the typical  tag for including (for example) typekit or google analytics code.

```
 %script{:type=>"text/javascript"}
  //your code goes here - dont forget the indent!
```

Comment: Haml did not add `CDATA` for me, nor did `%script` work for me if there were any irregular indentations in the js.

Comment: This doesn't work, throws a illegal nesting within plain text exeption

Comment: It works better if you need to add attributes to the <script> tag eg. id (which is in original question). I'm using haml 4.0.7 –– you can switch-off cdata wrapper in haml options (--cdata) no that it matters much (I think).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [fileupload-jquery](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) in haml. The original js is below:

```html
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
  {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
      {% if (file.error) { %}
        <td></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
        <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
          <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
          {% } %}</td>
        <td class="name">
          <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
      <td class="delete">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
          <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
          <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% } %}
</script>
```

At first I used the `:cdata` to convert (from [html2haml](https://html2haml.herokuapp.com/)), it doesn't work properly (Delete button can't remove relevant component in callback).

```html
<script id='template-download' type='text/x-tmpl'>
      <![CDATA[
          {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
          <tr class="template-download fade">
          {% if (file.error) { %}
          <td></td>
          <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
          <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
          <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
          {% } else { %}
          <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
          <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
          {% } %}</td>
          <td class="name">
          <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
          </td>
          <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
          <td colspan="2"></td>
          {% } %}
          <td class="delete">
          <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
          <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
          <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
          </button>
          <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
          </td>
          </tr>
          {% } %}
      ]]>
    </script>
```

So I use `:plain` filter:

```html
%script#template-download{:type => "text/x-tmpl"}
  :plain
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
    {% if (file.error) { %}
    <td></td>
    <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
    <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
    <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
    {% } else { %}
    <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
    {% } %}</td>
    <td class="name">
    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
    </td>
    <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    {% } %}
    <td class="delete">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
    <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
    <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
    </button>
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
    </td>
    </tr>
    {% } %}
```

The converted result is exactly the same as the original.

So `:plain` filter in this senario fits my need.

> :plain Does not parse the filtered text. This is useful for large blocks of text without HTML tags, when you don’t want lines starting with . or - to be parsed.

For more detail, please refer to [haml.info](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#javascript-filter)