# Javascript generation as response on create request with haml and formatted code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a form in Ruby on Rails, that handles creation of a new comment asynchronous.

I use `format.js` as a response and my code in the template looks something like this:

#### create.js.haml

```
- if (@comment.position)
  -# add the comment to the video
  -# do smthng
  if (window.Test == true){
    -# do something else
  }


-# do other stuff
```

The problem is, that I get a `Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal.` Error for the line that contains `//do something else`.

I know, I could simply remove the indention of this line, but I want to format my JS code as usual.

Any ideas how I can do this correctly?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744169/include-inline-js-in-haml

Comment: wrong haml comment syntax fix to `-# add the comment to the video` and `-# do smthng`

Comment: No, its not a duplicate, because in this situation the code with `:javascript` would return a js file that would include a `<script ...>..</script>` tag which would cause the response to fail, because this is no valid JavaScript file.