# Writing JS if condition inside something.js.haml

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing some JS code inside something.js.haml as a response to a JS request. Sample code:

```
var users_list_container = jQuery("#user_list .manager_list");

if(users_list_container.length > 0) {
  alert(); //Doesn't work
  console.log("#{escape_javascript( render :partial => 'some' )}");
} else {
  //Some Code
}
alert();  //Works here
```

> I get an ActionView::Template::Error (Illegal nesting: nesting within
>   plain text is illegal.): line 5

If I remove spaces before **console.log**, the code doesn't throw this error. But, alert doesn't get executed inside `if` block, but it executes outside it.

Please suggest, how can I write JS `if` condition inside **js.haml**

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9744196/3475678)

Comment: @Aleksey I need to use js.haml only. There is no point using **:javascript** inside **html.haml** if majority of my code is javascript

Comment: You cannot do this even in plain html. There is always `script` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't follow haml syntax properly in you `something.js.haml`. You have to follow indentation in every view file. Below code work for you.

```
var users_list_container = jQuery("#user_list .manager_list");

if(users_list_container.length &gt; 0) {
alert();
console.log("\#{escape_javascript( render :partial =&gt; 'some' )}");
} else {
\//Some Code
}
alert();
```